# Debezium MySql Connector - How to write changes to another MySql table?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I am trying to test Debezium in a standalone, non-docker environment, to copy changed data from one MySql table to another MySql table. The source and sink tables are the same structure in different databases (source db.table: testiot.INPUT_TEMP, sink db.table: tiotbak:INPUT_TEMP_BK). It looks like the source table is being read but the sink table is not created. Please help.

My source.properties file:

```
name=connect-mysql
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
tasks.max=1
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=3306
database.user=debezium
database.password=dbz
database.dbname=testiot
database.server.id=184054
topic.prefix=testiot
database.server.name=localhost
database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
schema.history.internal.kafka.topic=testiot.INPUT_TEMP_BK
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=testiot.INPUT_TEMP_BK
```

My sink.properties file:

```
name=connect-mysql
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tiotbak?user=debezium&password=dbz&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
topic.prefix=testiot
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=3306
database.user=debezium
database.password=Debez@01
database.dbname=tiotbak
database.server.id=184054
database.server.name=localhost
auto.create=true
insert.mode=upsert
pk.fields=DEVICE_ID
pk.mode=record_value
record_value=record_value
```

The command I am using to execute is:

```
sudo ./bin/connect-standalone.sh ./config/connect-debezium-mysql-worker.properties ./config/connect-debezium-mysql-source.properties ./config/connect-debezium-mysql-sink.properties
```

Comment: For starters, Debezium is only a source connector. Secondly, sink connectors do not use `topic.prefix` setting, so your config is invalid, and you should be seeing an error in your terminal that says as much (topics or topics.regex is required). And `name` property must be unique over all connectors

Comment: You also will need this https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html